# Examples of what can be called a modular task?

Tags: ios, methods

I came across the term 'modular task' in Apple's own iOS app tutorial and I need more examples of modular tasks so that I can understand the concept better and when to make up specific methods for certain tasks.

The example Apple gave of a modular task in the tutorial was the need to load initial to-do items into a table view based app to make up a preliminary to-do list, and so the code for this was put into a method called loadInitialData, called by viewDidLoad, to specifically handle this task.

What actually defines a modular task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modular task** is a generic term that applies to any task that is wholly containable. It is not specific to iOS or objective-c; it's a regular software development term. Basically, they're just encouraging you to break up your `viewDidLoad` method into smaller components using methods so that the contents are encapsulated, compartmentalized, and named.